# How to show the exact bibitem name when using cite?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I write my bibliography items like this

```
\bibitem{RS80} M.~Reed and B.~Simon, Methods of Modern 
    Mathematical Physics I, Functional Analysis, Academic Press, 
    New York, 1980.
```

and I would like `\cite{RS80}` to show `[RS80]` and not the corresponding number, e.g. `[1]`. (I have too many references at this point and numeric citation call-outs are starting to get very confusing.)

Comment: Have a look here: a) https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Getting_started_with_BibLaTeX, b) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners, c) https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex , just to mention a few.  Try also searching in this place, e.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbiblatex%5D+style .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please confirm that you use `biblatex` (and, possibly, `biber`). Or are you generating the formatted bibliographic entries -- such as the one shown in your query -- by hand? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote,

> I write my bibliography items like this ...

This creates the impression that you write the formatted bibliographic entries entirely by hand. If this impression is correct, all you need to do to achieve your stated formatting goal is to set the optional argument of each `\bibitem` to whatever you want it to say, e.g., `RS80`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[RS80]{reed-simon:1980} M.~Reed and B.~Simon, Methods of 
    Modern Mathematical Physics I, Functional Analysis, Academic 
    Press, New York, 1980.
    
\end{thebibliography}
```

With this modification in place, , the instruction `\cite{reed-simon:1980}` will output `[RS80]`, as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much! Nice that the solution is so simple.